# Possible to have split() start at index 1?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am wondering if it is possible to simply have split() start at specified char rather than 0. I am splitting routes by / and am getting an empty string as index 0 in the returned array. Not that this is a major issue but does anyone see a good fix?

ex.

```
let authorizedRoutes = [{ path: '/NY/emails'}]

{authorizedRoutes.map(route => {
    let splitRoute = route.path.split('/');

    console.log(splitRoute);
})}
```

results in :

```
["", "NY", "emails"]
```

Comment: Just filter the array and remove empty strings.

Comment: route.path.split('/').filter(x=>x)

Comment: @epascarello this works, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out the empty strings

```js
console.log('/NY/emails'.split('/').filter(x=>x))
```

Or you can use a reg exp to match the strings

```js
console.log('/NY/emails'.match(/([^\/]+)/g));
```